# Flutter: Instance member 'signInWithGoogle' can't be accessed using static access. (static_access_to_instance_member at )

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I try to lint for my Flutter project, I have a class API to log in and log out google account, Linter prefers to remove static before these methods (login with Google and sign out). I cannot call these functions in view. Here my code:

API.dart

```
class FBApi {
FBApi(this.firebaseUser);

  ...

  Future<FBApi> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    ...
  }


Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut().then((_) {
      print('***** log out...what the hell?');
      _googleSignIn.disconnect();
      _googleSignIn.signOut();
      // Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/login", ModalRoute.withName("/home"));
    });
  }
}
```

Login.dart error above

```
Future<bool> _loginUser() async {
    final FBApi api = await FBApi.signInWithGoogle();---> error
    if (api != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Logout.dart

```
Future<void> _signOut() async {
    try {
      await FBApi.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 79):

```
await FBApi.signInWithGoogle();---> error
```

should be

```
await FBApi().signInWithGoogle();
```

You first need to create an instance `()` to call an instance method.

Alternatively you can change

```
Future<FBApi> signInWithGoogle() async {
```

to

```
static Future<FBApi> signInWithGoogle() async {
```

to make `signInWithGoogle` available without creating an instance first.

I don't know what the intention actually is.

Comment: like the first method, you told me `await FBApi().signInWithGoogle();` but I have firebaseUser as a parameter of FBApi, how can I pass?

Comment: `await FBApi(firebaseUser).signInWithGoogle();`