# Pass function as argument Flutter - The instance member '_handleChange' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, arguments, flutter-web

I have a class that starts like this

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyClass({
    Key key,
    this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onChange;
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}
```

and need to pass the onChange from the parent. In the parent I have defined it like below, and have widget variable where I try to pass it to `MyClass`, like so

```
class _ParentClassState extends State<ParentClass> {
  Widget myWidget = MyClass(onChange: _handleChange,);

  void _handleChange(arg) {
    setState(() {
      someStateVar = arg;
    });
  }
}
```

This does not work, there are two errors

```
The argument type 'void Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function()'. 
The instance member '_handleChange' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Also: Is there a better architecture for passing a funcion that will set a state variable that is in the parent?

Edit: the first error was fixed using rstrelba answer below, now it only remains

```
The instance member '_handleChange' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

I was trying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415287/3808307 and doing

```
  Widget myWidget = MyClass(onChange: _ParentClassState()._handleChange,);
```

the error goes away but the stack is exceeded

Comment: Why are you creating a widget outside of the build method?

Comment: @nvoigt because I pass it to the build, and there can be different widgets depending on a condition, I already fixed the error by setting the myWidget in the inital state, I will post my own answer, with the fixes from the answer below and this fix

Comment: myWidget is a state variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
// 1. you can define the type of function you want to pass as a type like this
typedef ChangeCallback<T> = void Function(T value);

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyClass({
    Key key,
    this.onChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // 2. and use it like this
  final ChangeCallback onChange;

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}
```

Second Error Fix:

Solution 1:

```dart
class _ParentClassState extends State<ParentClass> {
  Widget myWidget = MyClass(onChange: (arg) {
    setState(() {
      someStateVar = arg;
    });
  },
);
}
```

Solution 2:

```dart
class _ParentClassState extends State<ParentClass> {
  Widget myWidget;

  void _handleChange(arg) {
    setState(() {
      someStateVar = arg;
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    myWidget = MyClass(onChange: _handleChange);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get The instance member '_handleChange' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: That's because MyClass is created before _handleChange, so it can't be accessed. you need to create your Widget after _handleChange is accessible or created them at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, this was the right answer, I didn't understand it when I first read it

Answer (score 1):

Some my code

caller:

```
catTree = CatTree(onChangeCat: _onChangeCat);
'''
  _onChangeCat(int catId) {
    //
    debugPrint('_onChangeCat callback!');
  }
```

UI:

```
class CatTree extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int catId) onChangeCat;
  CatTree({this.onChangeCat});
}
```

STATE:

```
class _CatTreeState extends State<CatTree> {
.....

>>>this.widget.onChangeCat(e.id);
}
```

Comment: I am still getting one of the errors, the one that says The instance member '_handleChange' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: >>>Widget myWidget = MyClass(onChange: _handleChange,);
move this code to initState()